# Neo4j bulk import and indexing

Tags: performance, indexing, import, neo4j, bulk-load

I'm **importing a big dataset** (far over 10m nodes) into neo4j using the **neo4j-import** tool. After importing my data I run several queries over it. One of those queries performs very badly. I optimized it (PROFILING, using relationship types, splitting up for multicore *support* and so on) as much as I could.

Still it takes too long, so my idea was to tell **neo4j** to start at a specific type of nodes by using the *USING INDEX* clause. I then could check how my db hits change and possibly make it work. Right now my database doesn't have indexes though.

I wanted to create indexes when I'm done writing all the queries I need, it seems I need to start using them already though.

**I'm wondering if I can create those indexes during the bulk import process**. That seems to be a good solution to me. How would I do that?

Also I wonder if it's possible to actually write a **statement that would create indexes for an attribute that exists on every single one of my nodes** (let's call it "type").

```
CREATE INDEX ON :(type);
```

doesn't work (label is missing but I want to omit it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are on Labels + Properties. You need indexes right after your import and before you start trying to optimize queries. Anything your query will use to find a starting point should be indexed (user_id, object_id, etc) and probably any dates or properties used for range queries (modified_on, weight, etc).

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Label(property)
```

Cypher queries are single threaded so I have no idea what you mean by multi-core support. What did you read about that, got a link? You can multi-thread Neo4j, but at this point you have to do it manually. See https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/01/06/multi-threading-a-traversal/

Most of the time, the queries can be greatly optimized with an index or expressing it differently. But sometimes you need to redo your model to fit the query. Take a look at https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/08/26/modeling-airline-flights-in-neo4j/ for some hints.

Comment: I should probably rethink my model. 90% of my queries don't search by any properties so finding a starting point is probably not as efficient as it could be for me? Also my nodes only have a single label. It would probably be a better idea to import that label as a node's property instead while using another label. That way I could easily index everything. What I meant by multicore support is what Michael Hunger mentions in a video about imports you can find here: [link](https://youtu.be/7beIWWFXcp0?t=16m28s)